# Is it possible to make Android device connect only a specific Wifi network?

Tags: wi-fi, security

i want to know if it is possible to restrict an Android device to connect wifi networks expect one specific network.

Scenario is:

An app will be installed to the Android device and then device will be given to workers. All features of the device such as bluetooth, nfc etc. will be disabled and USB port will also be disabled for security concerns. Workers should be able to connect only one specified wifi network but no other wifi networks.

---

Another option is to somehow lock the settings app so users (workers) won't be able to turn on or off bluetooth, and connect any wifi networks. Can it be done without using any 3rd party downloadable locker apps?

Thank you all for your answers.

Comment: I don't think this is the correct approach. I would rather check the Android Always-on-VPN enforced by a MDM solution (the latter is not for free). Because of the VPN it doesn't matter to which Wifi or mobile network the phone is connected, on network level it will always be only be visible through the VPN.

Comment: Have them delete connectivity to all other wifi networks (but I doubt anyone will). Maybe a (looking for the word (kind of like genii)) "a supervisory continuously running macro in the background" could delete all but the one you want. In Linux up can set-up a script to run each hour (say when the minute turns to zero) using crontab.